# flask - python - markdown to html

Tags: python, markdown

I'm building my first website using flask and HTML. Some of my data that I want to migrate to this website resides in Markdown format. I am trying to convert Markdown into HTML using this however, I cannot get my hear around it:

https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown

I import it into my *.py file not sure what are the next steps after. This is what I got so far

```
from markdown import markdown
html = markdown.markdown(text)
```

not sure what should be put into the "text" variable. Also I have my markdown data residing in an html file how do I reference that from here? I have read through the installation guide but it's not very clear for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs located at https://python-markdown.github.io/reference/#using-markdown-as-a-python-library

text is supposed to contain your markdown text. In the below example found in the docs, some_file.txt would be the file containing your markdown.

```
input_file = codecs.open("some_file.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
text = input_file.read()
html = markdown.markdown(text)
```

To get your text, you would need to parse it out of the HTML. There are several ways of doing this but we would need more information about the file to proceed. Is your HTML file stored locally? Where in the file is the markdown? A [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: I actually took a slightly different approach and created static file which got all my markup data. With the above example I got the code work however it prints out an empty file always. Here's what I got
input_file = codecs.open("static/firewall.md", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
text = input_file.read()
html = markdown.markdown(text)
output_file = codecs.open("templates/some_file2.html", "w",
                          encoding="utf-8",
                          errors="xmlcharrefreplace"
)
output_file.write(html)
When I check the output file "some_file2.html" its empty.

Comment: tried both .md and .txt extensions and making sure its UTF-8 but the file which get created is always empty.

Comment: It's always the small things that get you!